# Form text fields not equally the same

Tags: html, css

I have two input text fields in a form, however I can't get them to have the same height and length. Here's the HTML code:

```
<div class="city_form">
    <form>
        <input type="email" name="email" input placeholder="Email Address"/>
        <input type="text" name="text" input placeholder="Zip Code"/>
        <br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</div>
```

And the CSS code:

```
.city_form {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    padding: 2px 2px;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

city_form[type=email] {
    padding-left: 10px;
    width: 30%;
    height: 92%;
    font-size: 100%;
    border-radius: 8px;
}

city_form[type=text] {
    padding-left: 10px;
    width: 30%;
    height: 92%;
    font-size: 100%;
    border-radius: 8px;
}
```

And lastly, the output:

[image]

What am I doing wrong? Note: I'm new to web development.

Comment: It should be `input[type=email]` and `input[type=text]`

Comment: check your class name city_form[type=email] { its wrong class should start from . before so please .city_form[type=email]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your inputs is same style, you should use a class (not include type) for it:

HTML:

```
<div class="city_form">
    <form>
        <input type="email" name="email" input placeholder="Email Address"  class="form_input"/>
        <input type="text" name="text" input placeholder="Zip Code" class="form_input"/>
        <br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.city_form {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    padding: 2px 2px;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

.form_input {
    padding-left: 10px;
    width: 30%;
    height: 92%;
    font-size: 100%;
    border-radius: 8px;
}
```

Demo [Here!](http://codepen.io/huychau/pen/jAmGAW)

Comment: Thanks! It worked for me. I'll accept your answer when it allows me.

Answer (score 1):

```
.city_form {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    padding: 2px 2px;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

.city_form input[type=email] {
    padding-left: 10px;
    width: 30%;
    height: 92%;
    font-size: 100%;
    border-radius: 8px;
}

.city_form input[type=text] {
    padding-left: 10px;
    width: 30%;
    height: 92%;
    font-size: 100%;
    border-radius: 8px;
}
```

Or simply:

```
.city_form {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    padding: 2px 2px;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

.city_form input[type=email],
.city_form input[type=text]
{
    padding-left: 10px;
    width: 30%;
    height: 92%;
    font-size: 100%;
    border-radius: 8px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the . before city_form

```
.city_form {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    padding: 2px 2px;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

.city_form[type=email] {
    padding-left: 10px;
    width: 30%;
    height: 92%;
    font-size: 100%;
    border-radius: 8px;
}

.city_form[type=text] {
    padding-left: 10px;
    width: 30%;
    height: 92%;
    font-size: 100%;
    border-radius: 8px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your CSS to the following

```
.city_form input[type=text], .city_form input[type=email] {
padding-left: 10px;
width: 30%;
height: 92%;
font-size: 100%;
border-radius: 8px;
}
```

You're parent elements is a doc with the class of .city_form and the input elements are the child.

You're also repeating the same style block unnecessarily when you can just comma separate your targeted elements.

You could also just give your input elements the same class like .form-field and just define the styles for that class

Answer (score 0):

u have add . infront of class so add . like this .city_form[type=email] and .city_form[type=text]

follow this way

```
.city_form input{
padding-left: 10px;
width: 30%;
height: 92%;
font-size: 100%;
border-radius: 8px;
}
```